# Config IIS for serving Static files / CDN?

Tags: iis, optimization, scalability

Is there anyway to config IIS to serve static file like CDN? Like Gzip, Cache, E-tag, Mod-date?

And how should we config to make it very robust on massive requests?

I know it's a short question but that's all I want to ask.

---

To the question on the IIS version, i prefer 6 and 7 IIS. You can give your answer on either 6 or 7 :)

Thanks! I hope people find this question useful!

Comment: You forgot to mention the IIS version you are targeting.

Comment: 6 and 7.5, the most common nowaday.

Comment: Looks like the poster asked this on serverfault.com - http://serverfault.com/questions/115235/config-iis-for-serving-static-files-cdn

Answer (score -2):

regardless of the server (IIS, Apache, etc.):

You achieve robustness through scale.  Put 1000-2000 servers behind a few hardware load-balancers (F5's).  Monitor constantly to ensure they all have the same files.  Secure your file system so writes are allowed by only 1-2 users.  Spread them geographically across network providers, power suppliers and backhoe opportunities.

Or just outsource it to someone who's already done all of this.

Comment: This is a possible solution for bigger enterprise, but currently we run only on test, and currently we run on only a server, so something that might increase by few hundred ms on iis could be the best.